# SSRS multi axis chart issue

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I was wondering if anyone can help me with this issue I have been having for at least a good 10 hours now after playing with it. I am going to use the Movies database from wiseowl to illustrate this instead.

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT FilmReleaseDate
    ,FilmName
    ,directorname
    ,FilmRunTimeMinutes
    ,directorgender
    ,CountryName
    ,datename(M, FilmReleaseDate) AS [month]
    ,month(FilmReleaseDate) AS [month_no]
    ,year(FilmReleaseDate) AS [Year]
FROM tblFilm
INNER JOIN tblDirector ON directorID = FilmDirectorID
INNER JOIN tblCountry ON FilmCountryID = CountryID
WHERE FilmReleaseDate >= '2006-01-01'
```

now say I want to put this into a stacked chart with the movies from each country, the second axis will show the running minutes of the films. But the problem here is that I want the average for all countries, not for each one. Is there any way to do this so I have 1 line rather then 3 lines.

[image: Line graph on a stack bar as multi axis DESIGN VIEW]
here is how the out put looks like

[image: Preview Mode]

as you can see from output there are 3 lines for the 3 countries in the result, is there a way to get an average for all of them in one line rather then each one so the output will have only one line showing the average.

If anyone can help I will really appreciate it as I have spent countless hours on this. Any other info you need let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script. Then use the new field **D.AVGFilmRunTimeMinutes** on your chart. I added aliases on each table on the script. Just correct the aliases if they're pointing to a wrong table.

```
    SELECT A.FilmReleaseDate
        ,A.FilmName
        ,B.directorname
        ,D.AVGFilmRunTimeMinutes
        ,B.directorgender
        ,C.CountryName
        ,datename(M, A.FilmReleaseDate) AS [month]
        ,month(A.FilmReleaseDate) AS [month_no]
        ,year(A.FilmReleaseDate) AS [Year]
    FROM tblFilm A
    INNER JOIN tblDirector B ON directorID = A.FilmDirectorID
    INNER JOIN tblCountry C ON A.FilmCountryID = B.CountryID
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT AVG(FilmRunTimeMinutes) AS AVGFilmRunTimeMinutes,FilmDirectorID FROM tblFilm GROUP BY FilmDirectorID) D
               ON D.FilmDirectorID = A.FilmDirectorID
    WHERE A.FilmReleaseDate >= '2006-01-01'
```

Comment: Hi Aldrin, thank you for your response but it still seems to bring back a line for every country. Is there any way to get just one line to show this at all using expressions or something?

Comment: Hi everyone, still no Joy with this, anyone have an ideas or possibly point me to the right direction, i have exhausted all options :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason your chart is producing 3 lines instead of one, is due to the grouping in you chart for each month (determined by how many countries).

I don't know the structure of your table, so I would recommend adding another field to your dataset:

```
    YEAR(A.FilmReleaseDate) * 100 + MONTH(A.FilmReleaseDate) AS [YearMonth]
```

This will add a field with the format YYYYMM

Add this to your chart on your axis instead year and month_no.

In the Chart Data window, click the drop down next to the newly created Category Group for Year Month. Select Chart Group Properties, and copy the name. (It should be called something like - Chart1_CategoryGroup)

The final step is to modify the expression for your Film Run Time in the chart.

Click on the drop down next to FilmRunTimeMinutes, and click Series Properties.

In the value field use the following:

```
   =Avg(Fields!FilmRunTimeMinutes.Value,"Chart1_CategoryGroup1")
```

Replacing Chart1_CategoryGroup1 with what your Category Group is called.